# How to shorten year into two-number integer in Python?

Tags: python

I have a basic block of code, and a portion of it asks the user their year of birth. In order to complete the program, I need their year (e.g. 1997) to be shortened into a two-number integer (e.g. 97). At the moment, the only way I can work out is to subtract 2000, but obviously that barely works.

```
year=input("And finally, what's the year of your birthday? ")
shortyear=int(year)-2000
```

I have researched online into slicing strings and integers but none of them seem to work for me. I'm still extremely basic at Python but I'm guessing that there should be a way to select only the last two characters in an integer?:

```
intyear=int(year)
shortyear=year[-2:]
```

That doesn't seem to work for me, though. Hopefully, someone will have an answer that works!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't validate the input so using slicing or modulo could give you nonsensical output, you should use a while loop and verify the user enters a year in some realistic range which if you go by the [verified oldest person in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_verified_oldest_people) is 1875-now:

```
import datetime

this_year = str(datetime.datetime.now().year)
while True:
    year = input("And finally, what's the year of your birthday? ")
    if "1875" <= year <= this_year:
        short_year = year[-2:]
        break
    print("{} is not a valid year\n"
          "Please enter a year between 1875 and {}".format(year, this_year))

print(short_year)
```

Comment: Perfect, that's really helpful. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

you can use `year%100` to only get the digits within a century:

```
>>> 2000%100
0
>>> 2013%100
13
>>> 1985%100
85
>>> 1997%100
97
```

Answer (score 1):

For slicing to work (`year[-2:]`) you should not convert `year` to `int` (ie `year` needs to be a string):

```
year = '2016'
year[-2:]
>> '16'
```

Comment: Or you can work with integer and use modulo operator: `year % 100`

Comment: note that if the user enters spaces at the end `2016    ` this will fall apart, you would at least need to `.strip()` the string first to ensure whitespace is not taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

You want a function which takes the year as input and returns the last two digits as output.

Since the last two digits may start with a `0`, you need to return the output as a string.

---

Assuming that the input is an integer, here is one way for implementing it:

```
def TruncateYear(year):
    return '%.2d'%(year%100)
```

---

Assuming that the input is a string, here is one way for implementing it:

```
def TruncateYear(year):
    return year[-2:]
```